# Angularjs specific routing

Tags: angularjs

Ok my fellow friends and associates,

I am trying to display only information based off of a url: parameter,

I have a service that has save a ton of data so I can use it across my application, but the problem I am having is displaying the data that I want to show based off of my parameter.

so here is my route, I am sending my id based off an  link attribute

```
/CourseMaterials/:ID"
```

I have my service which stores all of my json objects  to use accross the app.

```
angular.module('app').service('SaveService', function () {
    this.textExpress = {};
    this.courseMaterials = {};
    this.courses = {};
    this.student = {};
    this.receipts = {};
    this.webOrders = {};

    return {
        //This saves the textExpress object to reuse
        getTextExpress: function () {
            return this.textExpress;
        },
        setTextExpress: function (t) {
            this.textExpress = t;
        },

        //This saves the courseMaterials object
        getCourseMaterials: function () {
            return this.courseMaterials;
        },
        setCourseMaterials: function (cm) {
            this.courseMaterials = cm;
        },

        //This saves the courses object
        get

Courses: function () {
            return this.courses;
        },
        setCourses: function (c) {
            this.courses = c;
        },

        //This saves the student object
        getStudent: function () {
            return this.student;
        },
        setStudent: function (s) {
            this.student = s;
        },

        //This saves the receipts object
        getReceipts: function () {
            return this.receipts;
        },
        setReceipts: function (r) {
            this.receipts = r;
        },

        //This saves the webOrders object
        getWebOrders: function () {
            return this.webOrders;
        },
        setWebOrders: function (wo) {
            this.webOrders = wo;
        },
    }

});
```

I am a little stumped at how to say to my controller of my new view display only this info from my service

```
CourseMaterials/:id
```

So an object I might have looks like this

```
CourseMaterials[0] {

course: cit298,
author: ben stein,
isbn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
}
CourseMaterials[1] {

course: cit298,
author: george stein,
isbn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
}
```

On my new page I want to display something based off of the course applicable to what a user has selected based of the params in the link.

That looks like

```
http://localhost:55436/#!/CourseMaterials/cit%20298 etc......
```

Comment: Use $routeParams to fetch the id like $routeParams.id and use it for your result

Comment: I understand that, but I cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: What is the problem? What are you passing in the url?